# Can we integrate jqGrid with Spring MVC and Oracle DB?

Tags: jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid. I am working on a project which requires much of the jqGrid functionality. I will be using Oracle 10g.

I have seen tutorials like [Krams tutorial of spring mvc and jqgrid with MongoDb](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-3-dynamic-mvc-using-jqgrid-and.html). But I am concerned that in the tutorial it is stated that "MongoDb is a database that uses JSON instead of SQL.". Can we use Oracle 10g in place of MongoDB? Is there a tutorial for this?

Comment: Gotcha :)
Finally, I got it myself :) ...modified the Krams codebase as per my requirement and it worked fine with Oracle 10g.

The tutorial was really a helpful.

Comment: hey can u plz share the working code with oracle??
in desperate need...!!!